# Using SSL over Microsoft ARR

Tags: ssl, iis-7, arr

Am trying to use SSL Offloading to to allow https on our webfarm. The only way we can get the SSL to work is to install the the certificate and and bind it in IIS on each server. However our farm is scalable and we need to be able to create servers and drop them as traffic levels change. We can't include the certificate in the server template because it corrupts and won't work properly.

However if I understand it correctly we should only have to install the certificate on the ARR server and SSL offloading should apply to all the other servers. However this doesn't seems to be working.

Whilst we can install the certificate wach time we create a server, this is an added hassle and seems like there should be a better way of doing it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use SSL Offloading which would only require the SSL certificates be installed at the ARR level, allowing you to add servers to your webfarm without certificate configuration.

What exactly isn't working when you try to do this?